# Openpyxl loading existing excel takes too long

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl for Python 2.7 to open and then modify a existing .xlsx file. This excel file has about 2500 columns and just 10 rows. The problem is openpyxl took to long to load the file (almost 1 Minute). Is there anyway to speed up the loading process of openpyxl. From other Threads I found some tips with read_only and write_only. But i have to read and write excel at the same time, so i can't apply this tips for me. Does anyone have any Suggestion. Thanks you very much

Comment: Not really but it might depend on what else is in the file. 25000 cells should load very quickly but you might have other items in the file which also get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that while i was getting reasonable times initially (opening and closing was taking maybe 2-3 seconds), this suddenly increased to over a minute. I had introduced logging, so thought that may have been the cause, but after commenting this out, there was still a long delay

I copied the data from the Excel spreadsheet and just saved to a new excel spreadsheet which fixed it for me.  Seems like it must have got corrupted somehow.

Note - saving the same filename as another filename didn't work, neither did saving the same filename on a local drive.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what you need to do with the Excel file, but I would try opening the .xmls file as Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('file path')
```

Comment: Pandas Excel support is limited by what xlrd supports and this is only a subset of the file format.

Comment: Using panda to open is off course faster, but after opening i have to read all cell (cell by cell) and write comments into excel for severals cells ( not blockwise or columnwise). Is it possible with panda ?